# In eclipse, how do I add step continue and pause buttons to the toolbar of the java perspective?

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse, how do I add the debugging buttons: step, continue, and pause buttons to the toolbar of the java perspective?  When I right click to customize perspective I don't see where I could add those buttons.

CLARIFICATION: I'd like to add these buttons directly to my java perspective if I can, I don't like switching back and forth between java and debug perspectives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under Window -> Show View -> Other, in the Debug group, open the Debug view in your Java perspective.  The Debug view has the step buttons you're looking for.

Open any other Debug group views in your Java perspective that you want to see.

If you're happy with your Java / Debug perspective, save it using Window -> Save perspective as...

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse on the top right corner there is a mode choosing button it will be by default set to java persective. Ypu can click on this button to change to debug mode and in the debug mode you will be able to see the buttons. 
 or you can use
F5 - for step in
F6 - for step over
F8 - resume